# How to get just text from Javascript querySelector

Tags: javascript, html

I have a tab on my page which contains tabs like this:

```
<ul>
  <li class="3 tabs__item active uiTabItem" role="presentation" data-aura-rendered-by="79:126;a" data-aura-class="uiTabItem" data-original-width="183">
    <a class="tabHeader" aria-selected="true" data-tab-name="3" tabindex="0" role="tab" aria-controls="73:126;a" title="Files &amp; Contacts" href="?tabset-563b2=3" data-aura-rendered-by="80:126;a" data-special-link="true">
      <span data-aura-rendered-by="81:126;a">
     </span>
      <span class="title" data-aura-rendered-by="83:126;a">Files &amp; Contacts</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Within the code I'd like to get the tab label in String format. So for the code above I'd like to return "`Files &amp; Contacts`", I'd like to do this using just vanilla JS as opposed to using jQuery or any other framework.

This is the code I have so far, I can target the correct active tab but not sure how to just retrieve the text:

```
var selectedTab = document.querySelector('.tabs__item.active');
console.log(selectedTab);
```

[CodePen link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LOdGRv?editors=1111)

Comment: `selectedTab.textContent`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `innerText` or `textContent` :

```js
var selectedTab = document.querySelector('.tabs__item.active');
console.log(selectedTab.innerText);
//OR
console.log(selectedTab.textContent);
//OR
console.log(selectedTab.innerText.replace(/&/g, '&amp;'));
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="3 tabs__item active uiTabItem" role="presentation" data-aura-rendered-by="79:126;a" data-aura-class="uiTabItem" data-original-width="183">
    <a class="tabHeader" aria-selected="true" data-tab-name="3" tabindex="0" role="tab" aria-controls="73:126;a" title="Files &amp; Contacts" href="?tabset-563b2=3" data-aura-rendered-by="80:126;a" data-special-link="true">
      <span data-aura-rendered-by="81:126;a"><!--render facet: 82:126;a--></span>
      <span class="title" data-aura-rendered-by="83:126;a">Files &amp; Contacts</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```